# HTML rendered inside canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am looking for a workaround way to improvise `-moz-element()` using `-vendor-canvas()` to essentially 'snapshot' an element in order to clone it without needing to actually clone the DOM. Are there ways to place actual HTML elements inside a canvas for rendering or reproduction within it? If not, how would you approach a task like this?

Comment: @akonsu it is a CSS function, `-vendor-` prefixes are used in not-yet-standard css properties, replace it with any of these: `-moz-` for gecko browsers (firefox), `-webkit-` for webkit browsers like chrome and safari, and `-o-` for Opera based browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML2Canvas is your best bet really: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

This might be a canvas feature in the future. The specification reads:

> A future version of the 2D context API may provide a way to render fragments of documents, rendered using CSS, straight to the canvas. This would be provided in preference to a dedicated way of doing multiline layout.

...but not today, and probably not for at *least* several months. A whole lot more has just been added to the canvas spec recently (independent paths, `drawEllipse`, `currentTransform`, `resetClip`) and hixie likes to add things in batches, first waiting for the major browsers to adopt ~90% of the last batch. So it will be a while.

Comment: Thanks, great, well-informed answer. +1